# Webpack - how to bundle dependencies into a separate file that will be included along the "regular" output flow

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a working webpack config file, that bundles my React application.
my config utilizes `webpack.ProvidePlugin` and `externals` option that looks like this:

```js
externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'react-router': 'ReactRouter'
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        React: 'react',
        ReactDOM: 'react-dom',
        ReactRouter: 'react-router'
    })]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to load React dependencies in one file, for instance **react-with-deps.js** and the actual application will reside in another file, **my-app.js**.
this structure will allow me to add multiple react applications, with a centralized dependency file.

> **my-app.js** is built just fine - without the externals.

What I'm missing is the **react-with-deps.js** files to be built from the `externals` list. 
I tried to include it as part of the `output` list, but it didn't work.

Will appreciate any clue for how to achieve that!

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to load react dependencies as `externals`? If you would install these dependencies as `npm` modules, you could [split application and vendor dependencies in two separate files](https://github.com/christianalfoni/react-webpack-cookbook/wiki/Split-app-and-vendors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`externals` are modules that you're explicitly saying are *not* included in your Webpack build, so you can load them in from elsewhere (a `<script>` tag, etc). You can't build a file from them, that would defeat the entire point!

I think what you're looking for is `CommonsChunkPlugin`:

```
entry: {
   "my-app": "your app's entry file",
   "react-with-deps": [
       "react",
       "react-dom",
       "react-router"
   ]
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js"
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "react-with-deps",
        minChunks: Infinity
    })
]
```

Comment: Looks like that's what I've been looking for!
just one more question: looks like what you did in the ```entry``` is enough for what I need. why do you suggest using the ```CommonsChunkPlugin``` too?

Comment: @DimaFeldman - If I rememeber correctly, using `CommonsChunkPlugin` makes it so that `react-with-deps` is your entry chunk (i.e. the one that contains all of Webpack's loader functions, stuff like that), rather than any of your individual app bundles - as long as you load that one first, it won't matter what order you load the other ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!